# Conditional Statements in Python

Tags: python, selenium

having a weird issue with Python that i'm hoping someone can help me out with (syntax related).

I have a selenium web scraper to scrape linked in posts. It has a for loop as follows:

```
for card in elements:
    profileDiv = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__meta')]") if card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__meta')]") else ""
    profilePic = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//img[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__avatar-image')]").get_attribute('src') if card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//img[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__avatar-image')]") else ""
    profileName = profileDiv.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__name')]").text
    profileDescription = profileDiv.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__description')]").text
    text = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[contains(@class, 'feed-shared-update-v2__description-wrapper')]//following::span[1]").text
    video = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@class, 'update-components-linkedin-video')]//preceding::video[1]").get_attribute('src') if card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@class, 'update-components-linkedin-video')]//preceding::video[1]") else ""
    image = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@class, 'update-components-image__image-link')]//descendant::img[1]").get_attribute('src') if card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@class, 'update-components-image__image-link')]//descendant::img[1]") else ""
```

this *works* however it breaks and exits out if it can't find one of these items - even though I have a ternary there to check if the item exists.

So, i'm wondering, what is the correct way to do this in Python:

1. Check if something exists
2. If it does, assign it to a variable
3. If not, skip.

I don't want to put this in a try...catch because theoretically a post can have a image or a video or none.

I know in Javascript I would just do:

```
let image = card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@class, 'update-components-image__image-link')]//descendant::img[1]") ? card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@class, 'update-components-image__image-link')]//descendant::img[1]").get_attribute('src') : null
```

thanks all

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but three of those are not protected by ternaries. If one of those three fails, your exception will propagate.

Comment: Yeah those three will always be there no matter what, so that's why I didn't add them. But I could for sure.

Comment: If `card.find_element(some parameters)` is going to raise an exception, then you cannot possibly avoid this by testing `card.find_element(the exact same parameters)`, because that would raise the same exception!  You need to use `try`/`except` here.

Comment: Please qualify the statement that " it breaks and exits". Also, your assignments are inefficient (find_element will be called twice) and prone to coding error if the parameters passed to find_element aren't identical. Better to call find_element once then check the return value and assign accordingly. Another option is to use an assignment expression (walrus operator)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer  - you have to use find_elements in Selenium, which returns a boolean value.

````
        for card in elements:
            profileDiv = card.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__meta')]")

            if profileDiv:
                profileDiv = profileDiv[0]

            if profileDiv:
                profileName = profileDiv.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__name')]").text
                profileDescription = profileDiv.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__description')]").text

            profilePic = card.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//img[contains(@class, 'update-components-actor__avatar-image')]")
            if profilePic:
                profilePic = profilePic[0].get_attribute('src')

            text = card.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[contains(@class, 'feed-shared-update-v2__description-wrapper')]//following::span[1]")
            if text:
                text = text[0].text

            video = card.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@class, 'update-components-linkedin-video')]//preceding::video[1]")
            if video:
                video = video[0].get_attribute('src')

            image = card.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@class, 'update-components-image__image-link')]//descendant::img[1]")
            if image:
                image = image[0].get_attribute('src')
    ```
````

Comment: *find_elements* does **not** return a boolean value - it returns a list

Comment: It seemingly does, or returns something that can evaluate into a Python boolean.

Comment: A Python list that is not empty is *truthy* in a boolean context. Try *print(bool([]))* and *print(bool([1]))* for further enlightenment